# Which function is called to mine a block, broadcast the newly mined block & receive a newly mined block?

Tags: bitcoind, block, mining-technical-details, bitcoin-core-development

I am trying to understand the control flow and handling of transactions in the memory pool.

Comment: These are all different functions. Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: @NickODell When a new transaction is received it is added to the memory pool (after checking for conflicts). While mining, only the transactions which are in the pool are considered. What happens to the transactions after they are included to a newly mined block? Are they moved to another data structure from pool? If yes, Which function handles it ?